# String en vez del jlabel

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo una interface con 60 jlabels, nombrados asi:
A1 A2 A3....A60

La idea es cambiarles el color de acuerdo a una condición, pero tendría que poner 60 "if". La idea sería por medio de un string cambiar el label.

La línea de código para cambiar el color es esta:

```
Ventana.A2.setForeground(color.GREEN)
```

Pero el valor de A2 lo tengo en un string llamado "celda", lo ideal sería poner

```
Ventana.(celda).setForeground(color.GREEN)
```

Java no permite esto, alguna idea de cómo se hace?.

Comment: Hola juan sanchez, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta crear una ArrayList de tipo JLabel, así podrás acceder por medio del numero de posición

```
    JLabel[] etiqueta = new JLabel[60];
    ArrayList<JLabel> lista = new ArrayList<>();//Lista de tipo JLabel
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        etiqueta[i] = new JLabel("A" + i);//Inicializas c/u de los JLabel
        lista.add(etiqueta[i]);//Se van agregando a la lista
    }
```

Entonces así puedes cambiar si sabes la posición

```
lista.get(25).setForeground(Color.yellow);//Si conoces la posicion en la lista
```

O por un determinado rango

```
for (int i = 15; i < 30; i++) {
        lista.get(i).setForeground(Color.yellow);
    }
```

O filtrando la búsqueda por determinado nombre por ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        if (lista.get(i).getName().equals("Ventana")) { //Este se lo asignas con la función .setName y es diferente al nombre que muestra la JLabel
            lista.get(i).setForeground(Color.yellow); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te puedes crear un Hashmap:

```
HashMap<String,JLabel> listaLabels = new HashMap<String,JLabel>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 60;i++){
   listaLabels.put("A"+i, new JLabel(""+i));
}
```

Y así para cambiar color de cualquier label haces:

```
listaLabels.get("A2").setForeground(Color.yellow);
```

:D.

Answer (score 0):

no se entiende mucho amigo Juan, pero quizas lo conveniente seria usar un metodo en cual le pases un label y asi lo llamas dependiendo de lo que necesites, ejemplo:

```
public void cambiaColor(Label variable, color tipo){
Ventana.variable.setForeground(tipo);
}
cambiaColor(A2, color.GREEN);
```

Bueno, asi me lo imganio, dios quiera te sirva

Comment: Hola @srJJ, muchas de las respuestas que escribes son del tipo "no se entiende la pregunta, pero prueba esto..." Por favor, lee [answer]. Si una pregunta no se entiende, no se debería responder, sino pedir aclaración al autor en los comentarios.

Comment: Bueno, lo tendre en cuenta, cosa que no comparto ya que mi tiemo es limitadoy no puedo esperar a que el interesado responda, por ende doy mi respuesta desde lo que se entiende. sin animo de generar controversia

Comment: Comprendo 100% lo del tiempo limitado, pero entonces ¿no sería mejor usarlo respondiendo a preguntas claras y bien definidas en lugar de usarlo respondiendo a preguntas que al no estar completas pueden acabar cerradas y/o eliminadas? (perdiéndose así la respuesta y el tiempo invertido en ella)

Comment: Bueno señor... lo tomare muy en cuenta, gracias por su guia